# How to get with GHC.TypeLits.TypeError a type error at compile time and not at run-time?

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families, type-level-computation

Till now, I assumed, that GHC executes a type level function (type-family) at compile time. Therefore an error message triggered by the TypeError type-family should be issued at compile-time.

In the following example, I get the type error at run time.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
import GHC.TypeLits

type family If c t e where
    If 'True  t e = t
    If 'False t e = e

type family EqSymbol (a :: Symbol) (b :: Symbol) where
    EqSymbol a a = 'True
    EqSymbol a b = 'False

type family Lookup (x :: Symbol) (l :: [(Symbol,t)]) :: t where
    Lookup k '[]             = TypeError (Text "Key not found: "  :<>: Text k)
    Lookup k  ('(x,a) ': ls) = If (EqSymbol k x)  a  (Lookup k ls)

type TList =  '[ '("foo", Int), '("bar", String)]

test1 :: Lookup "foo" TList
test1 = undefined

test2 :: Lookup "bar" TList
test2 = undefined

test3 :: Lookup "baz" TList
test3 = undefined
```

For the function `test3` the evaluation of the type-level function `Lookup` should give a type error, because *baz* is not a key in `TList`.

GHCi loads the code without a type-error:

```
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :l SO.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( SO.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

Querying the types of the functions `test1`, `test2` gives the exepected results:

```
*Main> :t test1
test1 :: Int
*Main> :t test2
test2 :: [Char]
```

Querying the type of the function test3 gives a type error and the TypeError function is only executed when I try to **evaluate** the `test3` function:

```
*Main> :t test3
test3 :: (TypeError ...)
*Main> test3

<interactive>:5:1: error:
    • Key not found: baz
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: (TypeError ...)
```

What do I have to do, to get a compile-time error?

Comment: Note that the above is not a runtime error, but a compile time error when compiling the `test3` call. "When checking the inferred type" means compile time. I don't know, however, why the source file compiles. Perhaps you need to "use" `test3` instead of only defining it?

Comment: @Chi: Yes, Adding a new function `test4 = test3` gives an error when reloading the file into GHCi. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this doesn't cause an error when compiling your module is lazyness. It's basically the same reason that `print (if True then 1 else error "Mearg")` doesn't cause any problems: because the `else` branch is never actually *used*, there is (provably!) no way the error-raising expression could influence the result. If you will, the error only happens in an alternative universe.

Likewise, you never make any use of the type information that `test3` could (well, not-!) supply. I.e. you never evaluate the `Lookup "baz" TList` result, not at compile-time nor at runtime. So there is no error!

In any real program using such a type family, you *would* however be interested in concrete type information, and do things like

```
show0 :: (Show q, Num q) => q -> String
show0 q = show $ 0`asTypeOf`q

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show0 test3
```

And that does cause a compile-time error (twice in fact, for some reason):

```
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:~$ ghc /tmp/wtmpf-file2798.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/wtmpf-file2798.hs, /tmp/wtmpf-file2798.o )

/tmp/wtmpf-file2798.hs:35:19: error:
    • Key not found: baz
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘show0 test3’
      In the expression: putStrLn $ show0 test3
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = putStrLn $ show0 test3
   |
35 | main = putStrLn $ show0 test3
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^

/tmp/wtmpf-file2798.hs:35:19: error:
    • Key not found: baz
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘show0 test3’
      In the expression: putStrLn $ show0 test3
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = putStrLn $ show0 test3
   |
35 | main = putStrLn $ show0 test3
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```